# Will a reading list be useful for newcomers?

Tags: discussion

The [computer-science.SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599) did it, and I suggested it on [cryptography.SE](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1519) (and helped with a few entries)

I've no DSP background, but participating on SE taught me one thing: the longer a site existed, the more likely new questions are dups. So maybe it sends people onto the right track faster?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! That's a great idea!  Can you please edit your question and give some links to examples on other SE sites, so we can see what you mean?

Comment: Edited. Sorry, it's not Physics.SE, it's Computer Science SE, I remebered wrong.

Comment: [OK! I've started up a question copying (mostly) the CS.SE starter question.](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1815/80)

Answer (score 2):

To try to figure out what the top-level keywords are, I've exported all the tags from the site and generated a wordcloud that scales the tag label with the number of questions about that topic.

Code is:

```python
from stackapi import StackAPI
SITE = StackAPI('dsp')
SITE.max_pages = 100
tags = SITE.fetch('tags')
word_frequency = {}
for i in tags['items']:
    word_frequency[i['name']] = i['count']

from wordcloud import WordCloud

wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,
                background_color ='black',
                min_font_size = 10).fit_words(word_frequency)

wordcloud.to_file('word_cloud.png')
```

[image: A word cloud generated by the tag frequency in SE.SP.]